# How can i remove unused iCloud keys from entitlements using ionic config.xml or an azure DevOps task?

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i'm having this error when trying to archive my xcode project on azure devops.

> error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key
> 'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development,
> Production}, but no value was provided

I'm not using iCloud support on my app, so i don't need them, but these keys are being auto generated:

> com.apple.developer.icloud-services *
> com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers
>
> com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers

iCloud option is disabled on my app Identifier.

[image]

How can i remove these icloud keys from config.xml or an azure devops task?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i had to create a container on my 'certificates and profiles' page, enabled iCloud option, and it worked at the first try.